# i am trying to calculate sentimental score of each syntax of csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, csv, dictionary

this is a function of counting sentimental score of each syntax
and i am getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Public/Downloads/Hotelsurvey.py", line 116, in <module>
    Countswordofeachsyntax()
  File "C:/Users/Public/Downloads/Hotelsurvey.py", line 92, in Countswordofeachsyntax
    print(findsentimentalscore(nopunct))
  File "C:/Users/Public/Downloads/Hotelsurvey.py", line 111, in findsentimentalscore
    ss =ss + weight
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

```
def Countswordofeachsyntax():
    nopunct = ""
    with open('dataset-CalheirosMoroRita-2017.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter='|')
        for sys in csv_reader:
            for value in sys:
                nopunct = ""
                for ch in value:
                    if ch not in punctuation:
                        nopunct = nopunct + ch

            print(findsentimentalscore(nopunct))
```

Answer (score 0):

It seams like you are trying to add a int to a list in `ss = ss+weight`, maybe try typecasting `ss` to a integer as i suspect you want a number instead of what is possibly a sting, but if you can update your question with the code for `findsentimentalscore()` where problem seam to be, then that would make it easier to locate the actual problem.

okay from the edit you suggested it might be weight that is the problem, try this `ss = ss + int(weight)`