# i am trying to calculate sentimental score of each syntax of csv file by using csv library

Tags: python-3.x, string, csv, dictionary, math

this is the error which i am getting. In the previous post i forget to put both function . In the first function i'm reading csv file and removing punctuation and send the string to second function to calculate the sentimentel score. this code give output for few row of csv file and then show this error i'm new in python

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/Public/Downloads/Hotelsurvey.py", line 116, in <module>
        Countswordofeachsyntax()
      File "C:/Users/Public/Downloads/Hotelsurvey.py", line 92, in Countswordofeachsyntax
        print(findsentimentalscore(nopunct))
      File "C:/Users/Public/Downloads/Hotelsurvey.py", line 111, in findsentimentalscore
        ss =ss + weight
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

def Countswordofeachsyntax():
    nopunct = ""
    with open('dataset-CalheirosMoroRita-2017.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter='|')
        for sys in csv_reader:
            for value in sys:
                nopunct = ""
                for ch in value:
                    if ch not in punctuation:
                        nopunct = nopunct + ch

            print(findsentimentalscore(nopunct))
def findsentimentalscore(st):
    ss = 0
    count = len(st.split())
    mycollapsedstring = ' '.join(st.split())

    print(str(mycollapsedstring.split(' ')) + " := " + str(len(mycollapsedstring.split())))
    for key, weight in keywords.items():
        if key in mycollapsedstring.lower():
            ss =ss + weight
            #print(key, weight)
    res = (ss / count * 100)
    return math.ceil(res)
```

Comment: Hi Izyan. Welcome to StackOverflow. You wanted to add second function, then instead of asking new question (but this time better), please edit your existing question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62657944/i-am-trying-to-calculate-sentimental-score-of-each-syntax-of-csv-file

Comment: Dealing with this error has been described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32542589/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-int-and-list

Comment: Does this answer your question? [i am trying to calculate sentimental score of each syntax of csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62657944/i-am-trying-to-calculate-sentimental-score-of-each-syntax-of-csv-file)